# How to initialize sqlite database which was downloaded and locally saved in device in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, read-write

In my flutter project, I have downloaded the a zip from server, saved it in local storage of my device and then extracted. So, the file saving and extracting portion is ok as I can see my downloaded file from device explorer, in the following path-

**/data/user/0/com.asif.myproject/app_flutter/sample.db**

But now the problem, when I am initializing the sqlite database in my dart it is showing some exception. Here's code given below:

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "sample.db");

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join(documentDirectory.path, 'sample.db'));
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);

    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path);
    return ourDb;
  }
}
```

So, for this code, while I am trying to initialize my sqlite database, it is showing me the following exception-

**

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> Unable to load asset:
> /data/user/0/com.asif.myproject/app_flutter/sample.db

**

N.B: I have added both read and write permission in **manifest** file like below:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

So, I need a solution to initialize the sqlite database from path mentioned above so that I can execute all the necessary query regarding this database.

Comment: Have you asked for storage permission from the user ?

Comment: It is not working though I allowed  storage permission.